# CSS3 Keyframes how to make a image circle run without moving

Tags: animation, css, geometry

I use CSS3 Keyframes to make a image circle run without moving, i means like a wheel but circle not moving, it stay as it is.

Here is my CSS code :

```
.step_7 { 
background: url(../images/step7.png) no-repeat center top, url(../images/outer_glow.png) no-repeat 0 -7px; 
top: 377px;
left: 417px;
width:102px;
height: 104px;
z-index: 4;
}
@-webkit-keyframes circle-run 
{
    0%{
        -webkit-transform:rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% 
    {
        -webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);
    }
}

.animation {
    -webkit-animation: circle-run 2s infinite;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function:linear;
}
```

Javascipt :

```
 $('.btn1_inv').click(function () {
        $('.step_7').addClass('animation');
    });
```

here is my sample code :
http://jsfiddle.net/vLwDc/25/

From these above code, my element run but it move a little bit, how can i fix it ? thanks in advance .

Comment: do you mean why is it wobbly ? if so it's coz width height are different so it will be like that as it's not a perfect circle

Comment: hi Val,
this is my mistake because my circle is not equally in width and height

Comment: I dont understand what you are trying to do, but how could anyone tell that the circle is animating if you had a perfect circle, you are basically just "animating something that looks static"

Comment: yes, when i have a perfect circle i just add keyframes that make my circle rotate from 0 to 360, because my circle have some arrow on it route, so when circle rotate from 0 to 360, it will look like the arrow orbit the circle

Comment: U can mark the answer below ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you mean why is it wobbly ? if so it's coz width height are different so it will be like that as it's not a perfect circle